# Can't set config.forceExit in LibGDX (Lwjgl3)

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

Here is my Desktop Launcher code:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        config.setForegroundFPS(60);
        config.setTitle("Game10");
        config.setWindowedMode(1240, 760);
        config.forceExit = false; // ERROR!!!
        new Lwjgl3Application(new GdxGame10(), config);

    }
}
```

In new LWJGL3 config.forceExit not working. I can't find any solution so far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no forceExit in config. So presumably you have a master application that runs a child libGDX component and when you end that child component you find that the entire application shuts down, when you want the master application to continue. I guess you are on desktop because Android would be OK. So you must want to avoid a full `System.exit`

i.e.
`Gdx.app.exit()`
shuts down everything.
So when you instantiate a libGDX application you instantiate based on the application type, so for me, I use the same as you

`final Lwjgl3Application application = new Lwjgl3Application(Services.GAME_CONTROLLER,config);`

and the implementation for exit is

```
    @Override
    public void exit () {
        running = false;
    }
```

This finished the while loop that drives the application i.e. kills the main thread. If you have -other threads- running in the background they keep going.

If on the other hand you were instantiating `LwglAWTCanvas` then your shutdown would be this.

```
@Override
    public void exit () {
        postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                stop();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        });
    }
```

which would shut down the entire application. Anyway so `forceExit` being -false- was to stop a full system exit killing all your threads. The forceExit was to "force" the other threads to finish. It doesn't do that anymore so the fact it is now missing should not matter, your background threads should keep going.

In other words, `config.forceExit = false;` is now the default behaviour for your application type so you don't need it.